# PhpMyAdmin take many times to load get_scripts.js.php

Tags: javascript, performance, phpmyadmin

I'm using phpmyadmin for along time.
But recent few months ago. it's very dificult to use it.
because get_scripts.js.php take many times to load, and sometimes phpmyadmin return blank page.

What's wrong with it, and how to fix its error?

Comment: Does your web server error and access logs contain any hints? When phpMyAdmin returns a blank page, are there corresponding error messages?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch there is no error return. sometimes its return blank page because server timeout. sometimes, its return webpage content but take long times to wait.